# f2py not creating .py file

Tags: python, f2py

I have downloaded python-asurv which comes with asurv.py, setup.py, twokm.f and twokm.pyf. asurv has `import twokm` in it, but this gives the error `no module named twokm`. I have tried typing `f2py2e.py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 twokm.pyf twokm.f`** in the command prompt and this gives no error (I have the files added to the system path) but does nothing but open up f2py2e.py in python. (I'm guessing it needs to create a file called twokm.py).

Note I already had numpy installed which comes with f2py, then accidentally installed f2py by itself, then uninstalled f2py, then upgraded numpy.

How do I get the module twokm?

**got this idea from the question "f2py installation not working under Windows" in stack overflow.

Comment: Have you tried installing with `setup.py`?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that. It gives me this error:                        `building extension "twokm" sources
  target build\src.win32-2.7\twokmmodule.c does not exist:
   Assuming twokmmodule.c was generated with "build_src --inplace" command.
error: '.\\twokmmodule.c' missing`